# Dual boot Win10/Arch installation problem

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot

After playing with Ubuntu for a few months I deciding to try and dual-boot Arch on my laptop so I found this step by step guide and followed it: https://gist.github.com/alecgerona/09ba790960c45ba609ec7a466394fb0e

After spending some time getting refind working at startup I was finally able to select between Win10 and Arch. Windows works but when attempting to boot Arch I got this:

```
:: running early hook [udev]
Starting version 246.6-1-arch

:: running hook [udev]

:: Triggering uevents...
ERROR: device '' not found. Skipping fsck.

:: mounting '' on real root
mount: /new_root: no filesystem type specified.
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
```

Based on suggestions to similar problems I've tried remaking the `refind.config` file, another common thing I've seen mentioned is the hook load order, but since `udev` is the first hook in the order I doubt I have the same problem. I assume its some sort of error within the uevents process, but I'm not really sure.

The computer is an HP Pavilion Laptop with an intel i-5 9300H, 8gb of ram, and a GeForce GTX 1050. It has a 256Gb SSD that I partitioned according to the guide above. I can supply more specific information as needed. I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Arch is... finicky. Please don't try following random guides. Arch has what is probably the best documentation in the Linux world, follow [the installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide) and follow it _exactly_. Does it work?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? And made sure Windows fast start up is off. Note Windows updates turn fast start up back on, so you may have to regularly turn it off.

Comment: After looking through the wiki and trying again from scratch I was able to get it working, thank you both very much! The wiki really is incredible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After resetting my system and following the Arch wiki installation guide exactly I was able to get it to boot correctly. From what I can gather I believe that my problem was that I was generating the fstab file before my EFI system was mounted correctly therefore I only had the UUID available for my root directory. I also used GRUB instead of refind this time around as I seem to like it better, and I wasn't enabling microcode updates previously though I believe the primary problem was the one previously stated.